# Referencing a key twice in a type

Tags: typescript

Apologies for the poor title, I'm having a hard time expressing this concept.

I have a type like this:

```js
type Foo = {
  a: number,
  b: string,
  c: boolean,
}
```

I want to reuse this type in the following way:

```js
type FooInfo = {
  property: keyof Foo,
  description: string,
  value: Foo[this.property]
}
```

The idea of this type, is that if `property` is set to `a`, then the type of `value` must be `Foo[a]` (so, a 'number').

Valid example of this type in use:

```js
const propA = {
  property: 'a',
  description: 'This is a',
  value: 5
}
```

I also tried to play with generics, but I want the type for `value` to be inferred.

Is there a way to do this with Typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it worth using unions combined with mapped types here:

```js
type Foo = {
  a: number,
  b: string,
  c: boolean,
}
type Values<T>=T[keyof T]

type FooToFooInfo = {
    [Prop in keyof Foo]:{
        property:Prop;
        description:string;
        value:Foo[Prop] // <--- same purpose as Foo[this.property]
    }
}

type Result = Values<FooToFooInfo>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKBDAXFAOwFcBbAIwgCcAaTKM-AZ2EoEsCBzWrAY3zIQAbCNgK0AvulCQoANWyCiERgB4AKgD4kagNoBrCCDgAzKGoC66KeGjw4auHYCSBY4hQYsWHQAVKcMCh2KAMjUztzXE8vGLB-SEpQXD8AgG46GKwAE2UeNjBgVjgCXGY2TnTMrwA3BSVcO1948ygAelaoFQBaHqhGbBJoMCJKMDhGaGxGWAQdYAALVkYAOjiAqlBLGMlJaxkAJWUiQWBkOTrlFTsHZ1c4DSA)

Comment: Thank you! while it's not an exact answer, it's actually a bit closer to what I was looking for.

Comment: You can also make a helper function and infer value prop. Are you interested in such solution?

Comment: I'm actually good with this answer, and implemented a variation of this, thank you! See here: https://github.com/curveball/a12n-server/pull/332

Comment: Sure, no problem